# 'Incorrect array shape.' error in converting from npy to binaryproto

Tags: python, numpy

I have `brainwash_mean.npy` file and it is a correct file with no error.

I am trying to convert the `npy file to binaryproto` and I have `'Incorrect array shape.'` error.

My code is

```
def convert_numpy_binaryproto(filename):
    print filename;
    avg_img = np.load(filename);
    #avg_img is your numpy array with the average data 
    blob = caffe.io.array_to_blobproto( avg_img);
    with open( mean.binaryproto, 'wb' ) as f :
        f.write( blob.SerializeToString())


def main(argv):
    convert_numpy_binaryproto(sys.argv[1]);


if __name__ == "__main__":
   main(sys.argv[1:])
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code worked for me.

```
def convert_numpy_binaryproto(path):
    print path;
    avg_img = np.load(path);
    #avg_img is your numpy array with the average data 
    blob = caffe.proto.caffe_pb2.BlobProto();
    blob.channels, blob.height, blob.width = avg_img.shape;
    blob.data.extend(avg_img.astype(float).flat);
    binaryproto_file = open('mean.binaryproto', 'wb' );
    binaryproto_file.write(blob.SerializeToString());
    binaryproto_file.close();
```